# Jquery and Java/jersey endpoint binding

Tags: java, jquery, json, jersey

I have a Java Jersey endpoint like this:

```
public Response changeState(@HeaderParam(CLIENT_HEADER_PARAM) @NotNull Long clientId,
            @FormParam("section") @NotNull String section,
            @FormParam("state") @NotNull Boolean state) {
     Map<String,String> result=new HashMap<>();  
     ........
     if(condition1){
       result.put("key1","val1");    
       return Response.ok().entity(composeJson(unsuccessMap(result))).build();
     }
     if(condition2){
       result.put("key2","val2");    
       return Response.ok().entity(composeJson(unsuccessMap(result))).build();
     }

}
```

Then on jquery side:

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty('key1') && data.key1=='val1'){
    swal({
       title: "Error",
       text: "KEY1 ERROR",
       type: "error",
       allowEscapeKey: true
   });
}
```

The issue is I don't like how it works this way. I need to remember magic constants, strings or numbers, then check it there, arghhhh :)

How to do that in the best elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

If the key & val data you put into JSON result are only for condition purpose, you might try to use alternative ways like passing Response message or even Status code instead.